# Skipping a Docmd line with an if statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have searched and searched and found nothing that's helping me on this one.

I have a table (ReassignedLoans) that is usually blank, so I want to skip the query being run, unless the table isn't blank. I'm fairly confident that an If..then is what i want, but the query is giving me a "type mismatch" error.

what am i missing?

```
If "SELECT count(*) FROM ReassignedLoans" < 0 Then
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "IDReassignedLoansUpdate"
End If
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Your count will never be a negative number.  Swap your operator to ">"

Comment: `"SELECT count(*) FROM ReassignedLoans"` is a `String` and `0` is an `Integer`.  You need to actually ***run*** the query.

Comment: Wow, it must be getting late in the day... missed that completely.  Use DCount

Comment: Thanks Steve, yeah i had it backwards (they always trip me up) but regardless of the direction, it gave me type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If DCOUNT("someField","ReassignedLoans") > 0 Then
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "IDReassignedLoansUpdate"
End If
```